# Table View crashes because of empty array iOS obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have ViewController named MessageDisplay in which a table view is programatically created. In that same ViewController, there is a button which leads to another ViewController name CreateMessage. When user clicks back button in navigation bar in CreateMessage, MessageDisplay screen is loads back and when I scroll the table it crashes. I added uilabel in a table view cell as shown inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.

```
     UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-60, 8,50,20)];
[dateLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNovaSoft-Regular" size:13]];
dateLabel.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];
dateLabel.text = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];;
[cell addSubview:dateLabel];
```

The Crash is occurring because of `dateArray` is empty. Values to the array are stored from a REST call response.The array is initialised in 'didReceiveResponse' function. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the crash?  Presumably an array out of bounds exception.  What value do you return from `numberOfRowsInSection`? - show this code.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds for empty array'         this is the error and in numberOfRowsInSection it returns the count of dateArray

Comment: You can try to set breakpoints at all dateArray assignment lines, e.g. REST call, and maybe others. After Back button, one of them must set it to empty

Comment: The REST call is done in ViewDidAppear function. So because of getting response the Array become empty at 'didReceiveResponse'. But I want to reset the list when coming back to screen. So that I need to do the REST call in ViewDidAppear itself. Is there any other possible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can prevent the crash by checking if you're going out of bounds with

```
    if ([dateArray count] > indexPath.row) {
        dateLabel.text = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```

but i'm guessing the problem comes from that array not being what it's supposed to be.
Can you paste the code where you assign the dateArray values ?

Comment: Sure, but it's the wrong way. You should be setting a 0 number in the tableview datasource for numberofrowsinsection, which is the correct way

Comment: i know,  that's why i've asked for the part where he initializes the array, so we could find the actual problem. this should be only a temporary fix in case he needs to make some progress on other parts of the app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should load the data only after you populate your dateArray. 
You can skip the component when the array is empty and reload the table when you get the response (this will refresh the view) - this solution is only if you can show the view initially without the dateLabel.
The other solution is not loading any data till you recieve the response.

Answer (score 0):

`[YOURTABLEVIEW reloadData]` In `didReceiveResponse` (After dataArray is updated).

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return dateArray.count;
}`

Besides: DO NOT addSubview on cell, add to cell.contentView instead.